# base64_decode this not working

Tags: php, image, symfony, file-upload, base64

I have a problem in a role I created in `symfony2.6`. I'm putting the words that I know where is this giving error because tested and it gets my data correctly.

If I copy it and put it on this [site](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) it generates the image.

```
$dat = preg_split("/,/", $base64Content);

$dat[1] = str_replace(' ', '+', $dat[1]);
if (!($fileData = base64_decode($dat[1]))) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(
        array(
            'message' => "Base64 decoding error."
        ), 400);

    return $response;
}
$fileName = $entity->getUploadPath() . "/" . uniqid() . ".jpeg";

if (file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData)) {

    $entity->setPictureUrl($fileName);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
}
```

But in the code snippet above my `$fileData` is not accessible. I can not see what it is given to show it is not false. My `file_put_contents` function does not work, and returns a 500 error.

Error:

> http://localhost:8000/security/web/user/1/submit/image/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The string that is in my `dat[1]` is as follows:

```
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
```

`Symfony` could see the following error on the line of `file_put_contents`:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(uploads/pictures/56c38912d5b4f.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Is it something about needing permission to write to the folder? Thus it is giving an error coseguir to not open the file when it should create it if not existence? How do I give this permission?

Comment: what is the error message (500 error) ?

Comment: the error 500 is because he made an ajax call and she was a server error.

Comment: so it may be very useful to analyse the error text. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Is there any way I can go to my json what $ fileData is receiving?